# What is the Windows shortcut key for unselecting all files?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I can select and unselect one file by using the shortcut keys `Ctrl` `Space`.

To select all files, press `Ctrl` `A`.

What are the shortcut keys for unselecting all files?

Comment: Normally just mouse click outside the blue (or other color of selection) selected area. Works for what I do.

Comment: @John I can use the mouse, but I specifically want to unselect all files by using the keyboard only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Keyboard only

1. Pressing <kbd>`Alt`</kbd> <kbd>`H`</kbd><kbd>`S`</kbd><kbd>`N`</kbd> one after the other seems to be the actual File Explorer unselect option emulating the press of <kbd>`Home`</kbd> and then <kbd>`Select none`</kbd>.

[image]

2. Pressing `F5` appears to undo any <kbd>`Ctrl+A`</kbd> operation in File Explorer and the Desktop, but it also refreshes the view when pressed but this seems to be the simplest way to undo a <kbd>`Ctrl+A`</kbd>.

**Other built-in Windows 10 "select all undo" workarounds** using shortcut keys only:

- If you <kbd>`Ctrl+A`</kbd> everything in a folder via File Explorer, <kbd>`Tab`</kbd> and then  <kbd>`Space`</kbd>  seems to unselect all files or folders but also changes the sort order.
- If you <kbd>`Ctrl+A`</kbd> everything on the desktop, then <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`Space`</kbd> appears to undo that selection but only worked on the Windows Desktop.
- If you <kbd>`Ctrl+A`</kbd> everything in a folder via File Explorer, <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`Space`</kbd> seems to pick the previously selected file before pressing <kbd>`Ctrl+A`</kbd> or the top most file (or folder) in the view.
- If you <kbd>`Ctrl+A`</kbd> everything in a folder via File Explorer, <kbd>`Page Up`</kbd> or  <kbd>`Page Down`</kbd>  will select the bottom most or top most file or folder in the view.
- If you <kbd>`Ctrl+A`</kbd> files only in a File Explorer view, pressing the key for the first character of any file name in that view will select only that file.

## Related Resources

[Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10)

Comment: I can confirm that Ctrl + Shift + Space partially answers my question; this shortcut works on the Windows Desktop, but it does not work elsewhere. Thank you, though. Your answer is clear and concise.

Comment: @COrNotToC There you go, I just edited my answer but I believe `F5` is the key you need to do what you ask.

Comment: F5 is an excellent workaround, but it is not the solution for every scenario. If I do not want to refresh the folder, then I will be forced to use the mouse to unselect all files. I have accepted your answer, though, because you have answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: @COrNotToC Okay, I just added a final edit for you. I think this does exactly what you want with a few shortcut keys for file explorer. You are welcome!

Comment: Thank you for adding the "Windows" tag to my query. The shortcuts with the Alt key are perfect. Super User is such a fun and helpful place! I was crucified on Stack Overflow.